# Derivative of integral of function over n-sphere is the flux outwards - step in proof involving partition of unity.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Let $N:\mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R^{n+1}$ be a vector field defined by $N(x) = \frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}$. Let $f:\mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$ be a $C^1$ function. Given a coordinate system $\mathbb X:U\to S_1^n$ for $U$ open in $\mathbb R^n$, we define $\mathbb X_r (u) = r \mathbb X(u)$. $\mathbb X_r$ is indeed a coordinate system. The next step would be to prove the following: Using partition of unity, show we can assume w.l.o.g $\operatorname{supp}f|_{S^n_r} \subset \operatorname {Im}(\mathbb X_r)$.

This is the first part in an exercise in which the following is proven:

$$ \frac{d}{dr} \left(\frac{1}{r^n} \int_{S^n_r}fd\sigma \right)=\frac{1}{r^n}\int_{S^r_n}\langle\nabla f,N \rangle d\sigma$$

I usually try my best to have some sort of attempt in finding a solution before posting here, but I'm not sure where to begin. I know the n-sphere is compact so given  coordinate systems with $U_\alpha$ as their domains we get an open cover for $S^n_r$ we have a finite subcover that can induce a partition of unity. But I don't really know how to proceed. Would appreciate any help.

A small note: This exercise was given in an analysis over manifolds I'm taking, but we haven't really covered anything of substance in differential geometry or more advanced fields (the most "advanced" integration theorem we've seen was Stokes' theorem), and so I'm not sure if the differential geometry tag is appropriate here.

Comment: Both sides are linear (additive) in $f$?